# MPU6050 won't ACK

Tags: i2c, msp430

[image: G2 LaunchPad (not) connected to MPU-6050]

I'm trying to get my MSP430 to talk to a MPU-6050 sensor via I2C.  If anyone can spot-check this hardware and see if there's a problem there, I'd be grateful.  The resistors are connected to the red rail.  Right now they're 2.2k, but I've also tried 8k and 10k.

And the code keeps getting snagged at the line indicated below.  Pretty sure the slave isn't sending back an acknowledge signal:

```c
    while (UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTP);             // Ensure stop condition got sent (UCTXSTP auto clears after STOP is sent)
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCTR + UCTXSTT;             // I2C start condition with UCTR flag for transmit
    while((IFG2 & UCB0TXIFG) == 0);     //UCB0TXIFG is set immidiately (UCB0TXIFG is set to indicate TXBUF is ready for more data) 
    UCB0TXBUF = registerAddr;           //write registerAddr in TX buffer
    __delay_cycles(1000);
    while((IFG2 & UCB0TXIFG) == 0);     // CODE GETS STUCK HERE.
                                                         //wait until TX buffer is empty and transmitted  
    UCB0CTL1 &= ~UCTR;                // Clear I2C TX flag for receive
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTT + UCTXNACK;    // I2C start condition with NACK for single byte reading
    while (UCB0CTL1 & UCTXSTT);             // Start condition sent? RXBuffer full?
    receivedByte = UCB0RXBUF;
    UCB0CTL1 |= UCTXSTP;                    // I2C stop condition
    return receivedByte;
```

Comment: Can you describe your troubleshooting?

Comment: Often, breadboard busses have an intentional break in the middle.  Are you SURE that your I2C busses are pulled high -- like you measured??

Comment: If you can capture some I2C activity with an oscilloscope, then please post it.

Comment: Does the "client" react in *any* way?

Comment: What address (`registerAddr`) are you using?

Comment: Why are you ignoring the [answer you got elsewhere](https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/166/t/510533)?

Comment: Confirmed breadboard's continuity with a multimeter.

Comment: I have confirmed that the I2C buses are at 3.5V.
The client device has no visible indicators or lights for me to check whether it's responding.
I haven't gotten around to making sense of that other answer.
I'm trying to remotely access registry address 0x75
I have tried implementing the answer I got elsewhere by not enabling interrupts, but that made no difference.

Comment: Here's how I understand things with the interrupts: whether they're enabled or not, the interrupt flags turn on and off and can still be polled manually.  Enabling interrupts only determines whether the flow of control is automatically transferred into the interrupt vector/routines.

Comment: Right. The point is, if you enable the interrupts *without defining any handlers*, you'll send your CPU off into the weeds, and it won't be able to accomplish anything useful.

Comment: @DaveTweed I did not know that, thanks!  I figured it'd just ignore things and move on with its life.

Comment: Oh, and some troubleshooting I forgot to mention: I wrote a loop to just look for an ACK signal from all I2C addresses beween 0x00 and 0xFB (an arbitrary upper limit.)  Nothing is reporting back.

Last time I put an o-scope to SDA and SCL, they were both just a steady high.

Comment: If your SCL is never going low, you are looking at the wrong pin or don't have your MCU properly configured for I2C, or you haven't figured out how to use the scope trigger.

Comment: @ChrisStratton You've made me think it's a software problem.  You brought up great points and I loaded up some code that _did_ work to get two MSP's to talk to each other.  I ran this code on the "wrong" hardware configuration, the hardware I'm trying to get to work now.  Obviously the software won't do what it's intended, but I _do have a clock signal_ now!  Going to dive back into the software, compare the two programs, and see what's up.  Thank you for your feedback.  I'm a little embarrassed that I didn't think to try this troubleshooting step earlier.

Comment: Troubleshooting I've tried so far:

Different MSP430's.  Identical models, different units.
With and without breadboard.
With and without jumper cables.  Currently have wires soldered into slave and inserted into female headers on Launchpad.
Different resistor values (2k, 8k, 10k).  Current slave's breakout board has built-in resistors.
Many different sample programs.  Variations include using interrupts, not using interrupts but relying on the built-in I2C functionality, 

What does work: I can make two MSP's talk over I2C.  What's an MSP430 got that an accelerometer doesn't?

Comment: That's trying different stuff and seeing what doesn't work, not troubleshooting.  You need to find a way to see the communications.  A Bus Pirate is probably our cheapest way in, though far from ideal.

Answer (score 1):

According to the photograph, the sensor's logic I/O reference voltage is not connected and floating.